# CSS: Get border color from element itself

Tags: html, css

How could I get the color of the element itself via CSS?
I wanted to have the same border color as the color of the text itself.

Example HTML:

```
<span class="status-name" style="color:#ff0000">Max</span>
```

CSS:

```
.status-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid ???;
}
```

The bottom border should have the color `#ff0000` now. I tried `inherit`, `auto` or even `attr(data-color)` (in combination with a `data-color="#ff0000"` attribute) but all makes the rule invalid for the browsers.

Please note that I need to solve this problem if possible via CSS because there are some thousands elements on the page with such classes and it's accessed mainly by mobile phones.
Also I know that setting CSS via `style` is not state of the art but there are hundreds of different color values and it's not reasonable to create for each color an own CSS class, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default borders inherit the color propertie of the box so set no color on the CSS declaration:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid;
```

Comment: Oh yes, damn that I didn't try this. Thank you!

Comment: The initial value of border color is the color of the element content. This is *not* inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.status-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

it will automatically inherit the `color`

Comment: Or more explicitly:  `border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;`

Answer (score 0):

```
// using jquery
$(document).ready
(
   function()
   {
      $('.status-name').each( function(index, element) 
      {
         $(element).css("borderColor", $(element).css('color'));
      }
   }
);
```

Javascript is much better to use in dynamic instances, as well as allowing adjustments to this rule easily in the future if you decide to allow changes that do not follow typical CSS rules. Otherwise, other answers should work for your needs.

Comment: No JavaScript tag on question and OP's asking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Understood, simply providing an expandable input considering my view on changing properties or style based on a dynamic rule, a step beyond what was requested in the case that the OP's rule were to change to a rule not handled by CSS nativly or another user views this question under different circumstances that do require this sort of modification.